# JRE terminated when setting a string property (SWIG, Java)

Tags: java, visual-studio, swig

I'm using SWIG to access a DLL in Java. Most things work fine except setting a string value to a char*. Then the JRE will be terminated.

example.h:

```
typedef struct {
  char* name;
  int number;
} MyStruct;
```

example.i:

```
%module example
%{
   #include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

Java:

```
int number = MyStruct.getNumber() # works
MyStruct.setNumber(123)           # works

String name = MyStruct.getName(); # works
MyStruct.setName("newName");      # crash
```

Also I tried to use Byte Arrays:

example.i (added):

```
%include "various.i"
%apply char *BYTE { char * }
```

The generation of the Java files works fine but the build crashes away:

```
"jstring cannot convert to jbyteArray"
```

The wrap code of says:

```
 SWIGEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_bla_VERSION_1DLL_1get(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls) {
 ...
 if (result) jresult = jenv->NewStringUTF((const char *)result);
 return jresult;
 }
```

Is that something like a bug? Using "various.i" should be fine, why does it generate something with "string" and not "NewCharArray"?

I'm using VS Express 2015, SWIG 3.0.10, Java 7, everything in x86.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and added some setters to my wrapper dll.

These setters do the "string magic":

```
void SetMyStructName(Object* obj, char* newString)
{
    char *b = new char[strlen(newString) + 1]{};
    std::copy(newString, newString + strlen(newString), b);
    obj->mystruct.name = b;
}
```

It's ugly but works for now.